# How can I change the window size of the manatee camera view?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I would like to know how you can change the size of the scanning window. Currently it's always showing in fullscreen mode. In the phoneGap documentation on GitHub I see there is an option there to call startScanning() with some parameters to set the size of the window. Unfortunately that doesn't work for the Titanium framework or I am doing something wrong. Can someone help me out with changing the window size? Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

Barcode is not implemented by default in the Titanium SDK. So it completely depends on the module you use for scanning a barcode.

If you use the module `ti.barcode` which is provided by Appcelerator it is, as far as I know, not possible to resize. However, [this module](https://github.com/mikefogg/SquareCamera) by Mike Fogg (SquareCamera) does offer support for a windowed scanning area on iOS.

The Scandit Titanium module also has support for smaller than 100% scanning windows.